# Kentico Multilingual site

Tags: kentico

I have a main site in English with hundreds of pages. Now we want to add more languages to the site. The thing is for all new languages, each site will have only a handful of pages (1-10 pages) - it's not a 1-to-1 translation, but rather some pages in local languages. My question is should I create new culture for each site (the URL will have the language-country pair), or should I treat those new language as micro sites/folders under the English site. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if there are only a few pages for each site, handle them as new languages in Kentico vs. using subfolders.  Easier to expand if you decide to add more than 10 pages.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely agree with Brenden, from my experience subfolders always cause more problems.

The benefits of creating new cultures for existing site tree are:

- SEO benefits as you can utilize canonical URLs and lang attributes
- ability to fallback some pages to the default culture
- add translated content on go as long as you need it
- you can manage some of the content globally in just one place

From my experience, you should go the subfolder / multisite route only if you have absolutely different content and presentation per region/culture.